# Spark s3a throws 403 error while same configuration works for AwsS3Client

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

Below are my versions for everything

```
<spark.version>2.3.1</spark.version>
<scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
<hadoop.version>2.7.7</hadoop.version>

<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.7.4</version>
```

And I have the following code that is submitted to spark-submit as part of a fat jar.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a", "DEBUG")

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "AES256")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", endpoint)

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.session.token", session)

spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.proxy.host", proxyHost)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.proxy.port", proxyPort.toString)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.proxy.username", proxyUser)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.proxy.password", proxyPass)

val credentials = new StaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicSessionCredentials(access, secret, session))
val config = new ClientConfiguration()
  .withProxyHost(proxyHost)
  .withProxyPort(proxyPort)
  .withProxyUsername(proxyUser)
  .withProxyPassword(proxyPass)
val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config)
s3Client.setEndpoint(endpoint)

val `object` = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key))
val objectData = `object`.getObjectContent
println("This works! :) " + objectData.toString)

val json = spark.read.textFile("s3a://" + bucket + "/" + key)
println("Error before here :( " + json)
```

The call using the AmazonS3Client works

```
This works! :) com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream@3f736a16
```

But I get the below error leveraging s3a

```
2018-09-12 20:45:59 INFO  S3AFileSystem:1207 - Caught an AmazonServiceException com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: D8A113B7B1AB31B9, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: AybHBDYJCeWlw2brLdL0Ezpg5PNTUs9kxUqr17xR6qnv3WTxUQ0T1Vs78aM9mG8bsjTzguePZG0=
2018-09-12 20:45:59 INFO  S3AFileSystem:1208 - Error Message: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: D8A113B7B1AB31B9, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden
2018-09-12 20:45:59 INFO  S3AFileSystem:1209 - HTTP Status Code: 403
2018-09-12 20:45:59 INFO  S3AFileSystem:1210 - AWS Error Code: null
2018-09-12 20:45:59 INFO  S3AFileSystem:1211 - Error Type: Client
2018-09-12 20:45:59 INFO  S3AFileSystem:1212 - Request ID: D8A113B7B1AB31B9
2018-09-12 20:45:59 INFO  S3AFileSystem:1213 - Stack
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: D8A113B7B1AB31B9, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: AybHBDYJCeWlw2brLdL0Ezpg5PNTUs9kxUqr17xR6qnv3WTxUQ0T1Vs78aM9mG8bsjTzguePZG0=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:976)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:956)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:702)
    at com.company.HelloWorld$.main(HelloWorld.scala:77)
    at com.company.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

As far as I know they should be configured identically. So I am at a loss as to why the client works but s3a is getting a 403 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by removing AWS Java SDK

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and replacing it with the 2.8.1 version of Hadoop AWS dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: where to change? i had the same problem.thanks

Comment: This does not work. I see the below error without aws-java-sdk in the class path.

`Exception in thread "init" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing obvious. That log4j setting needs to go to log4j.properties, but as the authentication chain deliberately avoids logging anything useful, it won't help that much

1. Hadoop [S3A troubleshooting docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#AccessDeniedException_.E2.80.9CAccess_Denied.E2.80.9D). This is the history of all stack traces seen.
2. try the [cloudstore](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore/releases) tool, explicitly written to do basic connector debug and generate logs which can be safely included in support calls.